# using os.Rename to move file, triggers CREATE then CHMOD

Tags: macos, go

using go's os like so:

```
os.Rename(oldpath,newpath)
```

and watching the destination folder using [fsnotify](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify)

causes 2 events to fire, `CREATE` and `CHMOD`

can't seem to understand why `CHMOD` is fired.

- tried listening with python's [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)
  shows 2 events as well, file creation and folder modification.
- parent folder perms are `0777` file perms are `0666` (default).
- I'm on macOS

Comment: The fsnotify FAQ points to https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify/issues/62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JimB pointed me to the correct answer, this is a bug concerning with macOS spotlight indexing.

If anyone want's to track this, [reported bug](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/issues/15#issuecomment-282775574)